# Composer is resolving by SSH protocol instead HTTPS in Travis

Tags: github, https, composer-php, travis-ci

When jobs are executed in travis a credential error is returned

```
0.34s$ ./composer.phar config --global github-protocols https
0.36s$ ./composer.phar update nothing
Loading composer repositories with package information
Failed to clone the git@github.aaa/aaa.git repository, try running in interactive mode so that you can enter your GitHub credentials
```

Even when in composer.json is included the url with https

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/aaa/aaa.git"
    },
    ....

],
```

Then on .travis.yml file

```
language: php

before_script:
  - wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
  - chmod +x composer.phar
  - ./composer.phar config --global github-protocols https
  - ./composer.phar update nothing
  - ./composer.phar install

script:
  - mkdir coverage-report
  - ./bin/phpunit --coverage-clover coverage.xml --coverage-html coverage-report --log-tap tap.tap
```

I am not sure if this is related to composer, travis or both.
Anyway, is there any solution to this? It is required to go by token authentication.